# Rewrite dynamic URL's and delete ".php" extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic, url-rewriting

I have a problem with my .htaccess file. Well, I'm trying to do two things; Delete the extension ".php" of all the URL's, like: "localhost/about.php" to "localhost/about" or "localhost/about/". And rewrite a dynamic url: "localhost/user/index.php?usr=username" to "localhost/user/username/" or "localhost/username".

I have have found a method to do both things. But if I have the code to delete the ".php" extension, the code to rewrite the dynamic url doesn't work. And if I don't have the code to delete the ".php" extension, the code to rewrite the dynamic url works.

That's the error that the website gives me when I try to open a profile page:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /user/enric was not found on this server.

or

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /user/enric.php was not found on this server.

What can I do? Here is the code of the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^channels/page/([0-9]+)/?$ channels/index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^channels/([_0-9a-z-]+)/?$ channels/index.php?o=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^channels/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ channels/index.php?o=$1&p=$2 [L]

# Delete ".php" extension and adds "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

# User profiles
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/$ /user/index/?usr=$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

**SOLUTION, BY [JON LIN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851273/jon-lin)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^channels/page/([0-9]+)/?$ channels/index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^channels/([_0-9a-z-]+)/?$ channels/index.php?o=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^channels/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ channels/index.php?o=$1&p=$2 [L]

# User profiles
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/$ /user/index.php?usr=$1 [L]

# Delete ".php" extension and adds "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a check that when you add the `.php` extension to a request, that the php file actually exists, and you should move your user rewrite *before* your php extension stuff:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^channels/page/([0-9]+)/?$ channels/index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^channels/([_0-9a-z-]+)/?$ channels/index.php?o=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^channels/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ channels/index.php?o=$1&p=$2 [L]

# User profiles
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/$ /user/index.php?usr=$1 [L]

# Delete ".php" extension and adds "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate htaccess rule throughonline tools like
http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php